# Load custom collection with multiple category ids

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

I am using magento 1.9 version. I am having custom collection which consists category ids. I tried to get the collection based on the category ids. I followed [this link](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-filter-product-collection-using-2-or-more-category-filters/). 
I tried with this code too.

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('finset' => array($newArray))));
```

but returns the empty collection.
How to solve this.

Updates:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('custommodule/custommodule')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1);    
            $cat_ids = array();         
            $prod_ids = array();
            $result = array();
            $cat_ids = $collection->getColumnValues('category_id');
            $prod_ids = $product->getCategoryIds();
            $result = array_intersect($prod_ids, $cat_ids);
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('category_id',array('finset'=>$result));
            echo '<pre>';
        print_r($collection);
```

Comment: can you add more code? if it is a custom collection use `$collection->addFieldToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('finset' => array($newArray))));`

Comment: Yes updated with code. pls check

Comment: did you try this code `$collection->addFieldToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('finset' => array($newArray))));`

Comment: yes. but no result.

Comment: try this one `$collection->addFieldToFilter('category_id',array('in' => $newArray));`

Comment: tried that also. no luck

Comment: `echo $collection->getSelect();` post that query in question too. make sure you category array is correct.

Comment: yes the category array ($result) correct. $result has values.

Comment: did you check the query is working? mean give you correct result.

Comment: yes. Except this filter the whole collection working fine.

Comment: then your array is a problem try with direct injecting categoryid and check this is working `$collection->addFieldToFilter('category_id',array('in' => array(1,2)));` if work then your array problem

Comment: tried this this also, not works.

Comment: can you show how you save the category id in database table? mean every deal have single category or multiple category?

Comment: but when i print category ids using `$collection->getColumnValues('category_id');` it prints array of category values

Comment: you want to show the deal for current product category?

Comment: yes. i need to check the current product is in deal or not

Comment: go with this filter 
`$collection->addFieldToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('finset' => array($prod_ids))));`

Comment: am checking this in product page. it has the single product and deal is for the category.

Comment: i know i get the idea what you want this is the filter you need kindly test it

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have already pass array($newArray), so use below code

```
  $collection->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('finset' => $newArray)));
```

Comment: No luck. Returns the Same empty collection.

Comment: have you tried  $collection->addAttributeToFilter(‘category_id’,array(‘finset’=>$newArray)); ?

Comment: yes. but same empty result.